# Can anyone explain this php expression

Tags: php, regex

My question is what does this `'/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i'` means from the below code.

```
if(preg_match('/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i', $file)){
        $filepath = "images/" . $file;
```

Can anyone break it down and give me easy explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i` this is called a regular expression.
It's an expression that will match strings by the given pattern.
Let's break it down

`^` starts with
`^.` not a dot (.)
`-a-z0-9_.` any letter from `a-z`, `0-9`, `-` or `_`
`+` followed by
`a-z` any letter from `a-z`
`$` ends with
`/i` case insensitive flag

For more information, visit https://regex101.com/. You can put your regex into the input field to get a more detailed description

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Helps me to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Those are regular expresssions, which are pretty much universal across all programming languages. The purpose is to basically allow for quick matches in text patterns. It's useful for searching through large strings or files for finding keywords and seeing exactly where they are.